# Приходит пустой массив bs4

Tags: python, bs4

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://schools.dnevnik.ru/schedules/view.aspx?school=21457&group=1979146718386713618'
request = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, 'html.parser')

sheludes = soup.find_all('div', class_='scheduleWeekEditorParent')
 
print(sheludes.json())
```

Возращает пустой массив

Comment: не находить тег 'div' с классом class_='scheduleWeekEditorParent'. Могу предположить, что требуется авторизация в виде кода.

Comment: там авторизация требуется

Answer (score 0):

Для начала я бы посмотрел какое содержимое приходит в ответе:

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://schools.dnevnik.ru/schedules/view.aspx?school=21457&group=1979146718386713618'
request = requests.get(url)
print(request.text)
```

В качестве альтернативы для просмотра можно сохранить ответ в html файл, после чего открыть его в браузере:

```
with open('test.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(request.text)
```

---

И сразу станет понятно почему приходит пустой массив. Потому что тэга `div class="scheduleWeekEditorParent"` нет в теле ответа. Ответ из запроса к сайту != содержимому html страницы в devtools вашего браузера.

---

Что можно сделать?

Судя по всему, необходима аутентификация, которая обычно можно пройти с помощью `post` запроса. Предлагаю использовать `requests.Session()`. Вот пример:

```
data = {'login': 'GeniusOfPython0YO', 'password': 'hahaha'}
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.post('https://login.dnevnik.ru/', data=data)
    r = s.get('https://schools.dnevnik.ru/schedules/view.aspx?school=21457&group=1979146718386713618')
    ...
```

Может быть такое, что еще потребуется задавать заголовки(headers) и куки(cookies), чтобы сайт корректно отвечал.
Также советую посмотреть урок/обзор на devtools браузера и изучать вкладку `Network`